# Activar célula encontrada

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou com dificuldades em activar a célula que foi encontrada.

O código é o seguinte:

```
Private Sub cmdPesquisar_Click()

    'Verificar se foi digitado um nome na primeira caixa de texto

    If Txtnif.Text = "" Then

        MsgBox "Digite o NIF de um cliente"

        Txtnif.SetFocus

        GoTo Linha1

    End If

    With Worksheets("Central.de.Clientes").Range("F:F")

        Set c = .Find(Txtnif.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

        If Not c Is Nothing Then

            c.Activate

            Txtnif.Value = c.Value

            Txtempresa.Value = c.Offset(0, -1).Value

            Txttelefone.Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value

            Txtmorada.Value = c.Offset(0, 2).Value

            Txtlocal.Value = c.Offset(0, 3).Value

            Txtcontacto.Value = c.Offset(0, 4).Value

            Txtemailrel.Value = c.Offset(0, 5).Value

            Txtemailfact.Value = c.Offset(0, 6).Value

            'Carregando o botão de opção

            If c.Offset(0, 8) = "Masculino" Then

                OptionButton1.Value = True

            Else

                OptionButton2.Value = True

            End If

        Else

            MsgBox "Cliente não encontrado!"

        End If

    End With

    Linha1:

End Sub
```

Mas quando ponho a correr, aparece o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o debug identifica a linha:

```
c.Activate
```

Podem-me ajudar a identificar o erro no código?

Comment: Num teste rápido, o código funciona para mim. Pode ser o modo que está declarando as variáveis, que tipo de variável é `Txtnif` (TexBox? ComboBox?Célula?)? E adicione `Option Explicit` no cabeçalho do código, que é considerada uma boa prática, pois você precisará declarar todas as variáveis corretamente. E deste modo você está encontrando somente o primeiro deste valor, tente usar o [exemplo do método .Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)

Comment: Você está selecionando outra planilha no momento que realiza esta função? Adicione `Worksheets("Central.de.Clientes").Activate` antes do código com erro. Lembrando que é recomendado evitar o uso de Activate e Select, porém em alguns casos pode ser necessário a utilização destes. Principalmente se quiser focar no valor encontrado.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que está tentado ativar uma célula em uma planilha que está oculta ou não está ativa.

Tente ativar a planilha:

```
'[...]

' Ativar a Planilha:    
Worksheets("Central.de.Clientes").Activate

With Worksheets("Central.de.Clientes").Range("F:F")

    Set c = .Find(Txtnif.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then

        c.Activate
' [...]
```